# Which media queries technique to use

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there are any main advantages / disadvantages to the following methods of declaring media queries.

There seem to be 3 main ways - is there a reason for this? What is the difference?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:320px)" href="mobile.css">
```

versus

```
@import
```

versus

```
@media (within css file)
```

At the moment I use the link rel technique, but would be interested to know if the @media within the CSS file in particular, was in any way more efficient or considered better practice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two methods will cause an extra HTTP request to load another file; the final method includes all the variations in a single file.

It largely comes down to how you want to organize your CSS and how much difference there is in the CSS for different media queries. If it's easier for you to work on it in separate files, and you don't have a build process that will automatically combine them into a single file before deploying, then the first two methods are appropriate.

Use the HTML version if you want to reference each file directly, and if you want to see the media queries in the HTML. Use the `@import` version if you have a wrapper CSS file that will call in the appropriate CSS for the current medium, and you don't want your HTML cluttered with the various calls. In both cases, the media-specific stylesheets will be loaded as a separate HTTP request.

If you put all your CSS in a single file, or if you have multiple files but use a build tool to combine them into a single file, use the final method.

Answer (score 2):

this [page](http://komelin.com/en/5tips/3-simple-ways-declare-media-query) declares that the proper answer is:

Declare media query through `@media`

`@media all and (min-width: 480px) {…}`

It’s the most popular approach and it usually works fine.

But sometimes it’s necessary to split big CSS file and extract CSS rules for phone, tablet and desktop into separate files. In such case the following ways are reasonable...

Include into HTML page as a link

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="tablet.css" media="all and (min-width: 480px)" />`

Embed into CSS file through `@import`

`@import url("tablet.css") all and (min-width: 480px);`

Please note that *if you increase quantity of included files you’ll increase quantity of requests to the server and server load accordingly*.
So use this possibility wisely.